# How to setup ExternalDNS on Microk8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, high-availability, microk8s, external-dns

I have a Highly Available, 3 nods, Microk8s cluster with MetalLB and Ingress.

The cluster is supposed to serve a website with high availability.

I want to enable ExternalDNS for the website with the domain currently on Cloudflare (but I’m open to other free/commercial alternatives).

I have looked at the examples on the [ExternalDNS repository](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) but I can’t find any instructions for a similar setup.

Can anyone point me to a starting point, please?

Comment: Microk8s cluster does not differ anyhow from generic K8S on-premise/bare metal setup in context of ExternalDNS cluster ad-don installation.
You can try this [guide](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/cloudflare.md#setting-up-externaldns-for-services-on-cloudflare) from Kubernetes SIGs to setting up ExternalDNS for Services on Cloudflare.
Also useful information about [using CoreDNS and MetalLB on bare-metal Kubernetes clusters](https://sanisimov.com/2019/02/using-coredns-metallb-on-bare-metal-kubernetes-clusters/) described by Sergey Anisimov.

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin I keep reading that ExternalDNS needs etcd cluster to function and Microk8s doesn’t have etcd enabled. Don’t that make a problem when applying the config mentioned in the guide you provided?

Comment: Hello @Rojan Gh. In the provided [guide](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/cloudflare.md#setting-up-externaldns-for-services-on-cloudflare) there is no information about etcd. Maybe you read such requirement from any other guide, for example from [Setting up ExternalDNS for CoreDNS with minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/coredns.md)?
Did you try previously provided solution? If no, I recommend you to do it.